# Spring Data Jpa show

Tags: java, database, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have got a problem with my spring data jpa. When I do a select query instead of reciving the right results I get the first result duplicated the right number of times. So for example when I have such records in my database

```
Cat{ 'name':'johnny', 'status': 'Happy'}
Cat{ 'name':'johnny', 'status': 'Angry'}
Cat{ 'name':'johnny', 'status': 'Hungry'}
```

and I do a query `Select * from cats where name = 'johnny'` instead of receiving these 3 results i receive `Cat{ 'name':'johnny', 'status': 'Happy'}` duplicated three times.
What can be a reason of such a strange behaviour ?

In my real database I have unique keys on multiple columns, I thought maybe they need a special mapping ?

Comment: Can you add some code. Like how you are doing fetch call and your entity class

Comment: add entity and repository classes.

Answer (score 1):

If there are multiple records then you should return `List<Cat>` in your case.

```
List<Cat> findByName(String name);
```

Comment: It is simple if something there in db and then it should be returned.